# I want to read out the filenames of my multi upload form, and I want to include it in the database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

```
echo "<input type='text' class='form-control' name='jobCount' id='jobCount' value='".$_POST['count']."' hidden>";
    for ($y = 1; $y <= $count; $y++ ){
    <div class='input-group'>
      <div class='custom-file'>
        <input name='fileToUpload".$y."' id='fileToUpload".$y."' accept='image/*' type='file' />
      </div>";
    echo"</div>";
}
```

**and I picked it up in a way like the one below, but it didn't work**

```
 var z = "";
 for (var i = 1; i <= $("#jobitem").val(); i++) {
   if(i==1){
      z = z + $("#fileToUpload"+i).val();
   }
   else{
     z = z + ";" + $("#fileToUpload"+i).val();
   }
 }
```

Comment: Please post something closer to your actual code, which will actually run without syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your question was fairly vague so here is what I think you're looking for.
After you get the value of your uploaded files.

```
$files_uploaded = 'Get your uploaded files value here';
$uploaded_files = array();

foreach ($files_uploaded as $files){
  array_push($uploaded_files, $files);
}

$file_data = implode(", ", $uploaded_files);
```

Implode will add a ', ' after each file to break them up and make them more readable.
You can then use '$uploaded_files' in your SQL statement to insert into your DB.